# How to filter a queryset in django by excluding with two parameters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a view in django that looks as follows:

```
class ExploreListingView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ListingSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Listing.objects.exclude(user=self.request.user, claimed=True)
```

The result I expect is to filter out any listings that are assigned with the current user and are claimed, however the filter doesn't work, but when I remove either parameter it works just fine. How do I exclude it so I can use more than one parameter.

Comment: You exclude here `Listing`s given the *listing* is *of* the user *and* `claimed=True` (so if *both* conditions apply).

Comment: I have listings where both conditions apply but they are still seen in the queryset.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out all I had to do was chain the exclude methods, `Listing.objects.exclude(user=self.request.user).exclude(claimed=True)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Listing.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, claimed=True)
```

You select entries that field user is equal self.request.user and claimed is True

and you can use :

```
Listing.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).exclude(claimed=True)
```

both ways is worked but the first is clearly code.

Answer (score 0):

By "AND(&)" operator:

```
from django.db.models import Q
    Listing.objects.filter(Q(user=self.request.user) & Q(claimed=True))
```